# Page number disappeared after adding \usepackage{graphicx}

Tags: graphics, page-numbering

I want to add some pictures to the essay but after adding `\usepackage{graphicx}`, the page number in all pages disappeared. If I delete `\usepackage{graphicx}`, all page numbers come back. The latex template is given by the college so I cannot make a lot of changes. What's happening to all the page numbers?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\setlength{\textwidth}{6.85in}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{-0.35in}
\setlength{\topmargin}{-1.0in}
\setlength{\textheight}{9.7in}
\setlength{\footskip}{1.0in}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\renewcommand{\refname}{LIST OF REFERENCES}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.0}

%You may use any LaTeX packages unless they change the font size, font family, margin, or line spacing.

\begin{document}

    

\begin{center}
\begin{LARGE}
Document Screening Essays
\end{LARGE}

\vspace{0.5cm}

NAME OF APPLICANT: {\it Aaa Bbb}
%Replace with your name
\end{center}



\noindent \hrulefill


\noindent
{\small {\bf Subject 1.} Briefly explain your motivation for applying to our department, presenting your concrete research topic. (0.5 pages)}

\vspace{-0.15cm}
\noindent \hrulefill




%%%%%Notes%%%%%%
%Follow the instructions on the department web page in writing your answers.


\vspace{9.3cm}  %Delete this line when filling this section.

\noindent \hrulefill


\noindent
{\small
{\bf Subject 2.}
Select one important tool in xxx (e.g., theorem, formula, methodology, and algorithm) that is related to the research topic you presented in Subject 1. About this tool, explain the following aspects in a concrete and precise manner by clarifying the relation to your research topic. 
(1) Details, (2) Significance in xxx, (3) Example(s) of its application. (1.5 pages)
}

\vspace{-0.15cm}
\noindent \hrulefill


\noindent
{\bf The selected tool:} {\it XXX} \\
%Replace XXX with the selected item.

\noindent
{\bf (1) Details}

\newpage    %Delete this line when filling this section.


\noindent
{\bf (2) Significance in XXXXXXXXX}

\vspace{12cm}   %Delete this line when filling this section.

\noindent
{\bf (3) Example(s) of its application}

\vspace{12cm}   %Delete this line when filling this section.

%%%%%Notes%%%%%%
%You should not write anything except LIST OF REFERENCES in the 3rd and subsequent pages. 


\begin{thebibliography}{99}
  \bibitem ...
\end{thebibliography}


\end{document}
```

Comment: You should not be playing with the layout parameters like this. Use the `geometry` package to set layout correctly. `graphicx` outputs the dimensions to the PDF settings, but yours are incomplete and thus end up being wrong.

Comment: Unrelated, never use `\bf`, it has been depreciated since 1993! If you read somewhere that `\bf` is a good macro to use in LaTeX then you should probably find something better to read.

Comment: Instead of `\bf`, you can use `\textbf{ }` or `{\bfseries  }`

Answer (score 2):

The issue is not with `graphicx`.  The changes you made to the page layout put the page numbers off the page.  For starters, if you remove `\setlength{\footskip}{1.0in}`, you should see the page numbers again.

Here is a nice reference for page layout:
https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Page_Layout

Many people use the `geometry` package to adjust page layout in a consistent way.

Comment: Oh! Thank you very much. And the reference is really useful !

Comment: the fact that the numbers vanish rather tha just being logically off the page is related to graphicx, as it sets the pdf dimensions to the specified page size.